# Hugo miss generating images and a few other folders

Tags: hugo

Here is the structure of my Hugo theme:

[image]

The site with config file is in `exampleSite` folder. After I run `hugo --config ./exampleSite/config.toml` command. A few files generated in `public` folder.

[image]

Some folders like `about`, `images` are missing.

But when I run `hugo` command in `exampleSite` folder. All files are generated.

[image]

When I add `debug` or `verbose` flags to the command, there is no error at all. What could be the reason?

Comment: So, you have a site (your local dir), and you've added a theme (under `themes/whatever`)? What's in your site's (not your theme's) `content` directory?

Comment: As you see, the parent folder is theme folder and the content fold is inside `exampleSite`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A minimal Hugo site

To build a Hugo site, this is the minimum setup that you need:

```
.
├── config.toml
├── content
│   ├── about.md
│   └── first-post.md
├── layouts
```

- `config.toml` is described in the [configuration docs](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration/). You'll want at least a `baseURL` and a `title` added.
- `content/` - this is where the writing goes; `Markdown` documents here get translated into `HTML` pages. More details in the [Content organisation](https://gohugo.io/content-management/organization/) chapter.
- `layouts/` - this is where the page templates go.

For more info on this, check the [Hugo directory structure](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/directory-structure/), part of the getting started guide.

At this point, running the `hugo` command, i.e. compiling your site, will output the result in the `public` directory by default. Without any `HTML` templates, you'll just get a sitemap and some RSS `XML`.

### Cue Hugo themes

In your case, you want to use a ready-built theme, so you need an extra `themes` directory, in which you can have one directory for each theme you want to use, e.g. `themes/my-hugo-theme`. In your `config.toml`, you need to set `theme = my-hugo-theme`, which is the directory name.

Using a separate theme means that Hugo will use the theme's layouts (`themes/my-hugo-theme/layouts/`) to generate your site's documents (`content/`).

#### `exampleSite/`

As a convention, themes posted on Hugo's library have an `exampleSite/` directory to show off all the available features. Those files are ignored when you use the theme in your own site.

What you could do is copy the stuff in `exampleSite` over to your own `content` directory, and run again. From there, you can just change the content and remove what's not used.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I solved the issue by move the theme into `exampleSite/themes/my-theme` folder.